Equivariant resolution of singularity making a pullback of a line bundle admit a root
I am considering the following situation. Let $X$ be an irreducible normal projective variety with an action of a linear algebraic group $H$, and we have a $H$-equivariant line bundle $L$ over $X$. We assume $X$ has a singularity of codimension $\ge 2$ and that $L|_{X^{reg}}$ admits a $H$-equivariant $N$-th root.
Is there a $H$-equivariant resolution of singularity $\pi:\widetilde{X}\rightarrow X$ such that the pullback $\pi^* L$ admits a $H$-equivariant $N$-th root?
Any suggestions or answers with mild conditions on $X$ would be greatly appreciated.
(After reading Sasha's comment I realized that I forgot to write down the assumption on $L|_{X^{reg}}$. It's added now.)

The simplest example of $X = \mathbb{P}^1$ and $L = \mathcal{O}(1)$ shows that this is not true in general.
